# Homography matrix in camera calibration

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projection-matrices

I have been following the slides from uzh on camera calibration(https://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/teaching/2020/03_camera_calibration.pdf) with direct linear transform.

On slide 33 they say that system should have rank 8 to have a unique(up to scale) solution for homography matrix.

$QH = 0$
where  $Q\in R^{2n\times9},H\in R^9$

Values of Q are known. H - homography matrix, which we have to find. Why can we only find the solution up to scale? Can't we have an exact value for homography matrix?

Comment: This might be because you are solving for the homogeneous coordinates. Rescaling them by a constant does not change the "real" pixel coordinates and the right hand side is zero so you can rescale the equation as much as you want. In this sense, all the solutions are exact. At least that is my understanding from the linked pdf.

Comment: @Korf, Do i understand it right that the reason we can only estimate it up to some scale is the fact that we do not know the depth(distance from object to plane)?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot confidently answer that since I know almost nothing about camera calibration. When I look at the $QH=0$ equation from the math point of view I see the "up to scale" determination (also seen on slide 14) as a feature of using homogeneous coordinates, not a bug.